# Using Microservice AppRole to Spring Cloud Config Server and Vault integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, hashicorp-vault

How to connect a Microservice with AppRole[in vault] to Spring Cloud Config Server with Vault backend.

I can see examples using the root token like curl -X GET http://localhost:8888/my-service/default -H "X-Config-Token: s.TmqaRA2lASdNhJZqqZy7y8pX". But I could not find any example that use approle to connect spring cloud config service.

But I do not want pass root token from micro services to spring cloud config server, instead each service will have app role defined which should be able to connect the spring cloud config which in turn connect to Vault and get data.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: Sorry not yet.. As a workaround I have bypassed spring cloud config server and connected to vault directly

Comment: @sherybedrock I found a solution, if your issue is still present.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when using a Spring Cloud Config Server as a central configuration broker.

I found the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1589) which provided a solution. In short you have to add the spring-vault-core dependency to your dependencies in order to add a valid token resolver for the AppRole authentication:

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle:**

```
implementation "org.springframework.vault:spring-vault-core"
```

This should fix the issue directly.
Of course the following [configuration](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/2.1.x/multi/multi_vault.config.authentication.html) has to bet set then:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          port: 443
          host: myvault.domain.com
          scheme: https
          backend: mybackend
          kv-version: 2 #required if secrets engine version is v2 (default: v1/1)
          timeout: 5 #seconds
          authentication: APPROLE
          app-role:
            secret-id: 1234567-234567-23456-12341
            role-id: 987654-3456-9865-1235
            role: my-role-name #optional
            app-role-path: approle #optional if non default (default: approle)
```

After adding the dependency, configuring and starting the service, the following log message appears:

> 2021-04-30 12:40:31.211  INFO 53327 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.v.a.LifecycleAwareSessionManager     : Scheduling Token renewal

The `X-Config-Token` header is then not required anymore.

For more information regardin the Vault setup, visit:

1. [AppRole Auth Method](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle)
2. [Setting up the AppRole auth method for a service](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/approle)

Comment: To add to the above answer. the active profile should be vault and authentication should be app-role and i have used '/' as profile separator
spring: profiles: active: vault cloud: config: server: vault: port: 443 host: myvault.domain.com scheme: https backend: mybackend kv-version: 2 #required if secrets engine version is v2 (default: v1/1) timeout: 5 #seconds authentication: app-role profile-separator: / app-role: secret-id: 1234567-234567-23456-12341 role-id: 987654-3456-9865-1235 role: my-role-name #optional app-role-path: approle #optional if non default (default: approle)